# elasticsearch order more complex than with the "sort" option

Tags: elasticsearch

I am making a query in which it receives several properties, these have the property "price" and the property "old price"

What I want to do is subtract between the two to be able to know which is the one that has lowered the most (the one that is on sale)

```
"sort" : {
        "script" : {
                "inline": "doc['oldprice'] - doc['price']",
  
        },
        "order" : "asc"
    }
```

I was looking at the elasticsearch documentation and I could find something that can help me, but the symfony development environment gives me an error "sort option [inline] not supported [reason: all shards failed]"

that is to say that the 'inline' option is not valid, I am working with version 2.4 of elastic, what other way could I achieve this logic apart from using the script option

```
"sort" : {
        "script" : {
                "inline": "doc['oldprice'] - doc['price']",
  
        },
        "order" : "asc"
    }
```

Comment: Version ES 2.4? You can't update version?

Answer (score 0):

## Tldr;

Version `2.4` has been deprecated since forever.
Maybe an upgrade should be considered.

I feel you made a typo in your script.
As [per the documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/2.4/search-request-sort.html#_script_based_sorting)

```json
{
    "query" : {
        ....
    },
    "sort" : {
        "_script" : {
            "type" : "number",
            "script" : {
                "inline": "doc['oldprice'] - doc['price']"
            },
            "order" : "asc"
        }
    }
}
```